# How to return status code if action return type is custom class in API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I have action that returns my custom class `MyClass`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<MyClass> Get([FromUri] int id)
{
   // return 403 ???
}
```

Is it possible to return response with 403 status code? Or only way for it to return `ActionResult`?
Don't want to rewrite action with other return type.

Answer (score 0):

(This is .Net Core)
Due to the signature, you'd be unable to do this. You should change your signature to :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromUri] int id)
{
    return StatusCode(403);
}
```